# How to cluster Spark java framework?

Tags: load-balancing, httpserver, spark-java

How can I cluster web server based on [Spark](http://sparkjava.com)?
I can't find anything about clustering in their documentation, but maybe there are some third-party tools?

Answer (score 2):

I will use nginx load balancing to cluster Spark.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html